# Multiple instances of a common component conflict data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I'm having a problem related to mat-table datasource. Here is my set up:
I create a common component named common-table ( I use this component in anywhere requires table data, I just need to pass in datasource and other attribute. Something just like this when I need to put the table in any other components:

```html
<app-common-table
  *ngIf="robots"
  [pageName]="constants.DEVICES.PAGE_NAME"
  [tableData]="devices"
  [displayCols]="robotTableColumns"
  [hasCheckbox]="true"
  (sort)="sortData($event)"
  [hasAddButton]="true"
  [haspdateButton]="true"
  (refreshData)="refresh($event)">
</app-common-table>
```

In one case, I display a full table with the first instance of app-common-table (assign the datasource of this first instance and the data will display on the first table instance),
[image]

Then I click on a button on top of table, a dialog with other instance of app-common-table ( basically I will need to reassign the datasource with different data again for this second instance of table) and all data display on this second table along with the first table behind the backdrop of dialog.

[image]

As you can see both table has checkbox on the left side. The problem is when I click select all checkbox in the second table instance, all checkboxes in the first table instance selected instead.
[image]

When I tried to debug to investigate source of the issue I found out that the method  that I use to select all the checkbox (even the whole common component app-common-table) just refer to the first table's datasource. I still don't know how to solve this. This is the function I use to select all checkboxes in the common component:

```js
selectAllChekboxes() {
  if (this.isAllSelected()) {
     this.selectionList.clear(); // it's SelectionModel
   } else {
     if (this.dataSource.filter !== null) {
       this.dataSource.filteredData.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
     } else {
       this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
     }
   }
 }
```

This is how I set datasource in ngonInit:

```js
setTableData() {
  this.dataSource.data =this.tableData;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.matPaginatorItem;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.matSortItem;
}
```

Comment: Please update your screenshots... They're blurry and unreadable.

Comment: I need to do so :( I just put it there for others understand my step only.

Comment: Please change your screenshots. They aren't much clear

Comment: You need to do so? If there's confidential data, then change the data to dummy data, because the screenshots as they are right now are completely useless.